# Readme for Spreadsheet Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, spreadsheet

I'm looking for a good set of documentation for the gem Spreadsheet.

It has a basic Guide with a few methods, but doesn't cover alot of functionality that (I think) is available, and is terribly organized.

Comment: Have you tried: http://spreadsheet.ch/ - there seems to be at least some documentation and tutorials

Comment: This Documentation helped me https://github.com/golive/dev-wiki/wiki/Ruby-spreadsheet-documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Referencing the link that @topek mentioned, here is a more specific link.

[This seems to be a useful guide for using Spreadsheet.](http://spreadsheet.rubyforge.org/files/GUIDE_txt.html)

I also added that text to the [Cheat Gem](http://cheat.errtheblog.com/). If you do a `gem install cheat` you can then do `cheat spreadsheet` any time to reference that information.

Enjoy!

UPDATE:
  For things like text-wrapping, [I found this StackOverflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599555/can-the-ruby-spreadsheet-gem-wrap-text)

It doesn't look like anyone has explicitly put together a document detailing all of the options, which is quite surprising. If you find the time, modify the [Spreadsheet @Cheat](http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/spreadsheet) to help others!

UPDATE 2:

[You may also find the API helpful](http://spreadsheet.rubyforge.org/classes/Spreadsheet.html)